# Fortran Package Manager build 32 bit code

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran90, fortran-package-manager

Is there a way to make Fortran Package Manager compile code as 32 bit (i.e. pass -m32 to gfortran?) I can't see anything obvious in the documentation so I've resorted to copying the output running that with -m32 added rather than using `fpm build`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compiler flags can be managed via the `--flag` option:

```
fpm build --flag "-m32"
```